# GMOD 3D2D Sign with website

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I'm trying to make a 3D2D Sign that has text on it and displays a website, so that i can walk around it and the website will stay in the same position.  So far I have got this code but don't know how to import the website.

```
include("shared.lua")

function ENT:Initialize()
    self:SetMaterial("models/shiny")
    self:SetRenderMode(RENDERMODE_NORMAL)
    self:SetColor(Color( 0, 0, 0, 255 ))
end

function ENT:Draw()
    self:DrawModel()

    local ENTPos = self:GetPos()+Vector(0,0,26)
    local ENTAng = self:GetAngles()
    ENTAng:RotateAroundAxis(ENTAng:Forward(), 0)
    ENTAng:RotateAroundAxis(ENTAng:Right(), 270)
    ENTAng:RotateAroundAxis(ENTAng:Up(), 90)

    local url = "https://www.google.com/"
    local webPage = vgui.Create("F1HTML")
    webPage:OpenURL(url)

    cam.Start3D2D(ENTPos + ENTAng:Up() * 2, ENTAng, 0.5)
    draw.RoundedBox( 2, -220, -62.5, 440, 227, Color(0, 0, 0, 255) );--Black Body
    draw.RoundedBox( 2, -220, -62.5, 440, 30, Color(255, 0, 0, 255) );--Red Title

    local FontNameTitle = "HUDNumber5"
    draw.SimpleText( "Server", FontNameTitle, 0, -33, Color( 255, 255, 255, 255 ), TEXT_ALIGN_CENTER, TEXT_ALIGN_TOP)

    cam.End3D2D()

end
```

Answer (score 1):

To display a website in 3D space like you are trying to do, I'd recommend using the [3D2D derma project by HandsomeMatt](https://github.com/HandsomeMatt/3d2d-vgui).

Derma can, as you may already know, be used to open a website in a panel.
Check the [Derma Basic Guide](http://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/Derma_Basic_Guide) on how to use derma.

It allows for you to draw derma panels in a 3D2D space, like you want!